# How to combine private variables of n threads in openMP?

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing, openmp

I have the following c++ code which needs to be correctly parallelised.

```
vector<vector<int> > particle_list(ncell,vector<int> (0, 0));
#pragma omp parallel num_thread(24)
{
    vector<vector<int> > particle_part(ncell,vector<int> (0, 0));
    int icell;
    #pragma omp num_thread(24) for 
    for (int i=0; i<ntotal; i++)
    {
        icell=cellno[i];
        particle_part[icell].push_back(i) ;
    }

   ***#pragma omp master
    particle_list[ncell].insert(particle_list[ncell].end(),...
    particle_part[ncell].begin(), particle_part[ncell].end());*** 
}
```

The code enclosed within *** is what I'm not sure about. What I'm trying to do is as following.
I have a private variable particle_part (a 2d vector) which being populated by each threads (in its own copy) in parallel. Once the job is done I want the contents in each copy of 'particle_part' be combined into a single particle_list variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `critical` section. Shown schematically, at the end of your parallel region add a critical section which will be entered one thread at a time (you may not need the `omp_get_thread_num()` part depending on what exactly you're doing).

```
#pragma omp critical
{
    global_variable_thingy[omp_get_thread_num()] += local_variable_thingy;
}
```

Comment: I tried but couldn’t succeed because the variable is a 2d vector. Can you be suggest something more specific to 2d vector

Comment: Your code doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. Is `ntotal` 24? If so, don't bother trying to parallelize it. There's not enough work to justify the overhead. If not, then `icell` will be overwritten, and anyway isn't used (that I can see).